# Matlab conditional sum of signals in matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a vector with positive/negative signals and zeros (no signals):

```
X=[0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,-1,-1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,-1,0];
```

I want to create a new vector that is a cumulative summation of `X`, with the condition that the cumulative sum may never exceed 3/-3 so that the output becomes:

```
Y=[0,0,1,2,3,3,3,3,2,1,1,1,1,2,3,3,3,3,2,2];
```

I can solve this through looping or `arrayfun` but my matrices are large in size and multidimensional and neither of these solutions scale very well.

Can my problem be solved through a vectorized solution? Thanks.

Comment: Fundamentally, there is no vectorized solution, because each result element is dependent on the previous one.

Comment: @Oli Yeah, I guess u r right. Just wanted to check, sometimes I have been positively surprised on here when I have been stuck. Thanks.

Comment: Your description of the problem could be easily vectorized, but it seems from your example that you want something slightly different. temp = cumsum(y);Y=max(min(3,temp),-3). If this won't do and you really need more speed, it's a very well-suited problem for a mex-file implementation.

Comment: @MatlabSorter Ehhhm, your suggestion does not actually produce the vector that I want as the end result as `cumsum` works independently of the min/max conditions. If you have any other potential solutions, please provide them as possible answers. Compiling the code might be the way to go but I am still in Trial&Error/Analysis mode and would rather not take that route now. Thanks

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: you should put your comment in answer, to mark this question as solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oli Charlesworth gave the answer to this in a comment. I am copying his comment as an answer so that this questions stops being shown among the unanswered questions.

> Fundamentally, there is no vectorized solution, because each result element is dependent on the previous one. – Oli Charlesworth Sep 13 '11 at 17:01

Comment: Hey, there are only 7 possible options based on previous input, so theoretically in can be scaled if running on more than 7 machines/CPUS. ]:) Each instance calculates all possible solutions and then return requested one. And once all instances calculates all solutions each one can instantly know, which solution is correct. In general it can be vectorised same way as non restricted version.